# Super mario bros "rounded" tile collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution

I'm working on a Mario bros clone with SDL and C++ (purely for educational porpuses / and for fun)
I got collision detection working by using AABB collision detection and resolving one axis at a time:

1. Check collision with X-axis first
2. Move entity if not collision is detected
3. Check collision with the Y-axis.
4. Move entity if not collision is detected

This is working great!
However, one thing that I really like about the original Mario bros is that tiles have some kind of "rounded" feel to them. I think this helps make the map feel more organic, see how Mario moves left when jumping on a corner in the original SNES game:

[image]

I thought of using a circle collider for mario instead of an AABB.
This would make Mario "fall" off the tiles if you step too close to the edges. But perhaps someone knows a better approach. I've been thinking about collision detection for longer than I'd like to admit.
I'd love to know if someone has a clean aproach to accomplish what the GIF shows.

Comment: I think that its not the block's collider being rounded, but Mario's.
It's veeeery common that characters use a rounded shape (not necessarily sphere / circle) so they can move up slopes easily.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. As you may have noticed the entity collision box is smaller than the sprite. It is actually a rectangle, taller than wider.
2. Do not move the entity outside of the block instantly. Move the entity out at some fixed speed.